# elastic search query with case statement

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have 2 questions that are related to one another.

**One**

Trying to get documents that have a timestamp between yesterday at 5PM until today at 5PM
I tried the following, but it does not work as expected

```
GET /my_index/_search
{

  "query": {
    "range": {
      "enddate": {
        "gte": "now-1d/d+17h",
        "lte": "now/d+17h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Two**

Is there an option to do a case/when query?

The final results should be showing records from 5pm yesterday until 5 pm today in cycles.

So, if it is before 5pm today, I need to query from yesterday. But if it is after 5pm && before 12am I want to query from today 5 pm and until now.

Thank you!

Comment: can you add a sample document

Comment: Here is a sample ->
`{
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "14ca69ba-8b58-4d19-95b6-07516882806c",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          ...
          "jobid" : 230426,
    ...
          "enddate" : "2020-04-09T03:03:45.000+10:00",
          "numbytesuncomp" : 1310720,
          "encrypted" : "No",
          "incrlevel" : 1,
          "appid" : 516,
          ...
          "retentiondays" : 28
        }
      }`

Comment: There is no way to do case statement in elastic search . This has to be handled client side.  For case 1 I am not able to see the issue. Can it be due to different timezones

Comment: @jaspreetchahal
How can I do it on the client side?
Not related to TZ. I have checked it a few times, but will check again and validate.
Cheers!

Comment: It is best to  create date in if else block in your client application and pass date time to elastic search query. To implement same in elasticsearch you will have to use script query which has poor performance